# Regarding telerik radEditor

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, telerik

In the Telerik.Web.UI.xml file I found this entry

```
<member name="P:Telerik.Web.UI.RadDataBoundControl.Skin">
            <summary>Gets or sets the skin name for the control user interface.</summary>
            <value>A string containing the skin name for the control user interface. The default is string.Empty.</value>
            <remarks>
            <para>
            If this property is not set, the control will render using the skin named "Default".
            If EnableEmbeddedSkins is set to false, the control will not render skin.
            </para>
            </remarks>



        </member>
```

that says RadControls are using skin named Default..Now what if I want it to be not default ..what if I want it to be some CustomSkin to be rendered and not default skin?? Where do I need to set the value for the skin I wanna use? I don't know much of XML..so asking

Whats this xml file for anyway? Only describing stuff? What IS the purpose of this xml file??

[EDIT]

Tried setting Skin globally in webconfig.xml as mentioned in [telerik's website](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/skinregistration.html) as follows:-

```
<add key="Telerik.EnableEmbeddedSkins" value="true" />
<add key="Telerik.EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet" value="true" />
<add key="Telerik.RadEditor.Skin" value="CustomSkin" />
```

This is not making any diff! is using default file only :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Skin` property of the component. See the [controlling visual appearance help topics](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/controlling-appearance-overview.html). The XML file is not related to setting skins.

Comment: I hv tried that..what I want is that RadControl to use Custom Skin by default...I have like soo many Rad Editor controls and setting skin property on each n every radEditor control is a pain so looking for ways other than that..thot I could change just one entry in some xml file or something that will set default skin as CustomSkin for ALL the radEditor controls..Any ideas?

Comment: yeah, you can set the skins globally -- check the "Global skin settings" section in the skin registration help topic -- http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/skinregistration.html

Comment: oh, I see you figured that out. You should, however, _disable_ the embedded skins...

Answer (score 1):

This is documentation data for intellisense to provide you with information in your IDE.

As per the documentation you would set the `Skin` property to be the name of the skin you would like to load in place of `"Default"`

Edit in response to comment:

If you want to set the Skin globally then just apply the custom skin you want for the particular control in the SkinFile.skin for your current theme..

```
<rad:RadEditor 
runat="server"
Skin="MyCustomSkin" />
```

Of course replace `MyCustomSkin` with the skin of choice.

P.S. I have no idea of `RadEditor` is the right tag so you may want to check that out as well as this code is assuming that your `TagPrefix` for your Telerik controls is `rad`.

Comment: I cant find the .skin file ..tried doing stuff in webconfig as mentioned in telerik's website..plz check updates above in my ques..thnx